# Combine multiple rows into one row - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

SQL Query is:

```
select 147443 as DPID, 0 as CoID, 'ABC2431953D' as MID
union 
select 147443 as DPID, 176821 as CoID, '' as MID
```

The result should be:

```
147443, 176821, ABC2431953D
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) like

```
;WITH Temp (DPID, COID, MID) 
     AS ((SELECT 147443        AS DPID, 
                 0             AS CoID, 
                 'ABC2431953D' AS MID) 
         UNION 
         (SELECT 147443 AS DPID, 
                 176821 AS CoID, 
                 ''     AS MID)) 
SELECT MAX(DPID)AS DPID, 
       MAX(COID)AS CoID, 
       MAX(MID) AS MID 
FROM   Temp
```

Comment: Ben & Srikanth - Thank you so much for your prompt help. Got it working. Thanks, Thomas.

Comment: @Thomas You are welcome. Please mark the one that you feel is the the best solution as the accepted answer. For more help read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to join your result sets

```
with a as (
   select 147443 as DPID, 0 as CoID, 'ABC2431953D' as MID
), b as (
   select 147443 as DPID, 176821 as CoID, '' as MID
)
select a.DPID, b.CoID, a.MID
from a
inner join b
    on a.DPID = b.DPID
```